# How to create global variables?

Tags: python, blender

I need to create a variable (an array of floats) that will be accessible and modifiable by python controllers. If you want to know why I need this, I'm trying to implement a neuroevolution and I need to store neural network parameters. I'm new to python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dictionary (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) which is accessible globally in Blender.

It comes with the GameLogic-library and is called **globalDict**

http://wiki.gameblender.org/index.php?title=GlobalDict

Usage:

```
import GameLogic

...

GameLogic.globalDict['Key'] = value

...

value = GameLogic.globalDict['Key']
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Do you know any good tutorials for blender-python because I can't fined any good ones. Or any other important links like that one. I'd be grateful.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged as if the link goes down so does this answer. Please include at least some of the steps required in the body of the answer itself.